# css-grid-gallery-img-description-more text management

Tags: html, css, gallery

I have a grid gallery here on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/domius/zndsobwr/). Everything is as expected. I added a description below the images. Works properly. Weird things happen when I try to add another text below the description. Inserting text in `div.count` element makes other images in the same row push out content below them.

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Everything works properly. What is the problem? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pchbmqug/

Comment: Yes everthing looks fine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained the problem better. If you only insert content in the first `div.count` element. The problem happens. Descriptions of other items vanish.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh ;)

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in a Stack Snippet. Code must be **in the question**.

Comment: @DominikKolesar still working fine, can you share fiddle that shows error

Comment: I've set the fiddle to show the problem. First row. Only first's item description is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve the problem:

```
.gallery img {
     width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: You just need too remove "height: 100%" from ".gallery img".

Comment: Thank you very much! :)